# In mongodb, how to access the element of an array in an object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, time-series

In a collection named "person". I have a document :

```
   { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("596ff5c050645be676ff5e50"), 
        "personID" : "16-5001:01", 
        "date" : ISODate("2016-10-14T12:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "heartRate" : {
            "minutes" : [
                {
                    "seconds" : [
                        {
                            "data" : NaN
                        }, 
                        {
                            "data" : 123.0
                        }, 
                        {
                            "data" : NaN
                        }, 
                        {
                            "data" : NaN
                        }, 
                        {
                            "data" : NaN
                        }, 
                        {
                            "data" : NaN
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "seconds" : [
                        {
                            "data" : 16.0
                        }, 
                        {
                            "data" : 12.0
                        }, 
                        {
                            "data" : NaN
                        }, 
                        {
                            "data" : 67.0
                        }, 
                        {
                            "data" : NaN
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

I am trying to access the value of a seconds's array:

```
db.personCollection1.find( 
 {$and: [
   {"personID":"16-5001:01"},
   {"heartRate":"minutes.1.seconds.3":"123.0"}
   ]},
{"_id":0,"personID":0,"date":1})
```

I am not getting the desired o/p. I want to first access the 1st
 `object(heartRate)--->minutes[1]-->seconds[3].`
 Is it possible to access or I am doing it wrong?.Please suggest

Comment: This simply is not a good structure for this sort of information. "Nesting arrays" is bad practice and generally unsupported for "update" operations, or matched query projection. See the [positional `$` operator documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/). This is also the opposite of a general "time series" structure, where in fact we "avoid arrays" and "nest objects" in order to allow concurrent updates. Generally speaking though the nesting is not even required, since it simply adds nothing and only causes problems.

Comment: Thank you for your early response. I have time-series data and tried to design a schema [link](https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongodb-time-series-data-part-2-analyzing-time-series-data-using-aggregation-framework)
Please suggest a better way to proceed. Any suggestions will be helpful.